# Command in lua table key fail

Tags: luatex

Considering this example, why a tex command inside tab key do not work, and how can I solve this issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\def\tempA{foo}
\def\tempB{bar}


\begin{luacode}
local tab={}
tab["foo"]="\\tempB" --this work
 -- tab["\\tempA"] = "bar" this fail ?  

tex.print(tab["foo"])

\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `tab["\tempA"]`

Answer (score 1):

For me with an up to date TeX Live, the following does work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\def\tempA{foo}
\def\tempB{bar}


\begin{luacode}
local tab={}
tab["foo"]="\\tempB" --this work
tab["\\tempA"] = "bar" --this fail ?  

tex.print(tab["foo"])
tex.print(tab["\\tempA"])

\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```